# How to re-instantiate page/viewmodel in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvmcross, uwp

I using `MvvmCross` to build my UWP application. I have views with their own view models.
  When I start the app then first time from Setting view navigate to Passcode view using `ShowViewModel<PasscodeViewModel>()`. Then it call view model and view constructor to build and initialize view. When user come back to setting view and again navigate to passcode view using same method like `ShowViewModel<PasscodeViewModel>()` then this time view and view model constructor not get called. Since unable to reinitialize passcode view. So it display previous instance of passcode view.

**Following solution I have tried**

I tried removing the backstack in the navigations but then also not constructor get call.

Also implement loaded event but this solution also not working for me.

Also implemented `Void Init()` in view model but this method also not get call.

I just want when I navigate to PasscodeView then each time it call constructor of PasscodeView and PasscodeViewModel.

So my question is how to force to re-initialize page and viewmodel each time while navigation??
Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you share your project or some sample code which can reproduce this issue to us for the investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set Universal Windows Phone apps page navigation cache mode "Disabled". I think its default value is "Required".

```
 public PasscodeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
    }
```

The above code work for me.

Comment: I don't think disabling NavigationCacheMode is a general fix for this issue. Required is need often - hence it is the default. You should separate the code you need initialized in constructor from that which needs to be initialized in the OnNavigatedTo event. The latter event will get called each time. Also, check NavigationMode in that event to detect NavigationMode,back or NavigationMode.New

Comment: @ezaspi Have a look at my answer which works with  NavigationCacheMode = required

Answer (score 3):

I needed to use **navigation cache** mode on **required**.

I resolved it for me with the not very clean solution to call init again.

```csharp
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ViewModel!= null && e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        var reqData = (string)e.Parameter;
        var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer>();
        var req = converter.Serializer.DeserializeObject<MvxViewModelRequest>(reqData);
        this.Vm.CallBundleMethods("Init", new MvxBundle(req.ParameterValues));
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

This code avoids to call init again on back navigation.